# After Effects: Parent a Camera's position to a Null-Object with specific Off-Set

Tags: after-effects, camera, 3d, after-effects-expressions

I am just struggling with a simple expression thing I guess.

I have a camera looking at an Object in 3D Space. Actually The Object is at [0,0,0]. The Camera's position is at [29,-1637,-2248].

What I am trying to do is, to move the camera. For a better workflow I want to parent the camera's position to the position of a Null-Object, also at [0,0,0]. The thing is the camera has to keep its offset from [0,0,0] and just move parallel with the null at [0,0,0].

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome Slim :) If the camera is parented to the null with the **pick whip** correctly, you can move it as you like, what exactly is your issue? I'm confused :)

Comment: @poor thanks for your reply, the problem is, when I simply parent it with the pick whip, the camera copies the exact same position of the null. What I want is a specific offset to keep form the camera to the null object

Comment: This only happens if you use the expression pick whip. Try to use the standard pick whip here: https://cdn.tutsplus.com/ae/uploads/legacy/009_beginners2/25.JPG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To drive an animation by another layer use the pick whip or the selection list to **parent** it. In the following example the `Camera (layer)` adopts all animation properties of the `Null`.

[image]

Note: `Camera` is a 3d layer in your case, make sure **3d layer toggle** is enabled for the `Null` too.